# How do i get the first option in a select in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the first option from a select. Does this work?

```js
dropDown = document.querySelector(".select")
if (dropDown[0].innerHtml === '0'){
   console.log('yes')
}
```

`dropDown` is my select. Inside there is `option value=o>o</option`. This logs "yes" but it gives an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: dropDown[i] is undefined

Comment: `document.querySelector(".select > option")` will return first option. `document.querySelectorAll(".select > option")` will return all option

Comment: okay thank you i will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rookie mind went this way:

```js
const dropDown = document.querySelectorAll(".select > option")

if (dropDown[0].innerHtml === '0'){
   console.log('yes')
}
```

or if you need to have different types of actions based on the options:

```js
options.foreach(option => {
   switch(option.innerHTML) {
     case "value":
       // code block
       break;
     case "value2":
       // code block
       break;
     default:
       // code block
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

```js
dropDown = document.querySelector(".select") // this will always return only one element.
if (dropDown.innerHtml === '0'){ // So no need to add `dropdown.innerHTML[0]`
   console.log("yes");
}
```

Let me know if you need further support.

Comment: thank you but i have more than one option i have currentName and dg, i want to see if currentName is the first option of the select, any ideas?